# system() executes shell command differently C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell

I need to run this shell command in a C++ script:

> "/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so" -o "/usr/local/lib/output_http.so –w /usr/local/www" -b"

This command launches an application which broadcasts a video feed. When I execute this command via system() in C++ the application doesn't start properly.

I use:

```
system("/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i \"/usr/local/lib/input_uvc.so\" -o \"/usr/local/lib/output_http.so –w /usr/local/www\" -b");
```

When I try to access the video stream after I started it with the C++ application the webpage returns:

> 501: Not Implemented!
>
> no www-folder configured

I can't expect you guys to give me an application related solution, but I'm wondering if there's a difference in the way commands from a C++ application using system() and commands directly entered in a terminal are executed.

EDIT: The application broadcasts the video stream on IP:8080. I access it by going to that IP in my browser. Usually it opens a webpage with the stream in it but when I execute the command with the C++ application I get that error.

Comment: What do you mean by "try to access the video stream"? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: The old idea of mis-placed quotes was wrong; I realize that `-w` is actually an option to `output_http.so`, so the whole shebang must be passed as a single parameter to the `-o` option, as shown [here](http://skillfulness.blogspot.com/2010/03/mjpg-streamer-documentation.html) or [here](http://www.acmesystems.it/video_streaming) etc.

In that case, check file permissions etc. Does /usr/local/www exist? Is it possible that you are running the shell command from a root shell?

---

Hey, I have a book recommendation, too, ["one of the best tech books ever published"](http://web.archive.org/web/20131017103447/http://www.osnews.com/story/12098/Book_Review_Advanced_Programming_in_the_UNIX_Environment): [Stevens' Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment). The guy knows -- sorry: knew -- what he was talking about.

Comment: What order of quotes do you suggest? I am just following a tutorial where they said I should use this command.

Comment: Hm. Does the directory exist, do you have write permission there etc.? You can check the running processes and their command line parameters with `ps -f` or the like (I always must experiment to get the right combinations of options for the `ps` command, perhaps throw in a `-e` or `aux` or whatever). Is there a debug/verbose option for the streamer?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function, or at the very least, check its returning error  code. I don't understand why you are using `"` inside your command (I believe that in your particular case, you don't need them; but in general beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)!). Read about [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)

You could use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) to at least get the output of the command.

Even better, code yourself the running of the `mjpg_streamer` program using the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (perhaps [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), [dup2(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) etc...). Read [*Advanced Lnux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) for more.